# Checking corrected entries of the form, when entered wrong, show div for a few seconds

Tags: javascript, hide, registration

I have two JS scripts. 
One is for checking corrected entries of the form (after clicking the 'register' button):

```
        Zikula.Users.NewUser.setup = function() {
            Zikula.Users.NewUser.formId = '{{$formData->getFormId()}}';

            Zikula.Users.NewUser.fieldId = {
                submit:         '{{$formData->getFormId()}}_submitnewuser',
                checkUser:      '{{$formData->getFormId()}}_checkuserajax',
                checkMessage:   '{{$formData->getFormId()}}_checkmessage',
                validMessage:   '{{$formData->getFormId()}}_validmessage',

                userName:       '{{$formData->getFieldId('uname')}}',
                email:          '{{$formData->getFieldId('email')}}',
            };
        }
```

And when some of the entries are wrong, then there is a shown div (warning message). I would like to hide this div after a while, e.g. with this JS:

```
        var timePeriodInMs = 5000;
        setTimeout(function() 
        { 
        document.getElementById("mydiv").style.display = "none"; 
        }, 
        timePeriodInMs);
```

I know second one has to be *somehow* executed together when the first one is loaded (user click on a button), but I'm not sure how to join them. Could anyone help, please?

UPDATE:

Registration button has such kind of code:

{button id=$formData->getFormId()|cat:'_submitnewuser' type='image' src='btn_register.png' set='icons/extrasmall'}

Thanks a lot.
Martin

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax you're using, but I assume that you have code somewhere that **shows** the div, right? Why can't you just do the `setTimeout` stuff right after you show the div? As for fading the div out, there are a number of ways you can accomplish this. You could use `setInterval`, or `setTimeout` with a recursive function (and steadily decrease the alpha of the div), or use jQuery's [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) function.

Answer (score 0):

There may be critical information missing from your question, but assuming not, this answer should help.

Wrap the second piece of code in a function, then call it from code that handles the appropriate event.  Something like this:

```
Zikula.Users.NewUser.setup = function() {
    Zikula.Users.NewUser.formId = '{{$formData->getFormId()}}';

    Zikula.Users.NewUser.fieldId = {
        submit:         '{{$formData->getFormId()}}_submitnewuser',
        checkUser:      '{{$formData->getFormId()}}_checkuserajax',
        checkMessage:   '{{$formData->getFormId()}}_checkmessage',
        validMessage:   '{{$formData->getFormId()}}_validmessage',

        userName:       '{{$formData->getFieldId('uname')}}',
        email:          '{{$formData->getFieldId('email')}}',
    };
    hideErrors();
}

function hideErrors() {
    var timePeriodInMs = 5000;
    setTimeout(function() 
    { 
    document.getElementById("mydiv").style.display = "none"; 
    }, 
    timePeriodInMs); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, but defined time (5s) is counted right when the page is loaded, not after the button is clicked. I also found this solution with hiding of div is not the best one, when there's more of such divs to be hidden. Is there any possibility to use some simple fade out function similarly or somehow *slow down* this hide function, please? Thanks once again

Comment: I assume you have code that handles the button click.  Move the *hideErrors();* call into that function.  OR change *var timePeriodInMs = 5000;* (5 seconds) to any number you like (seconds * 1000).